# how to map each month data according to month in row

Tags: sas

This is my balance table

| ID | Month | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apr-19 | 100 |
| 1 | Jul-19 | 200 |
| 1 | Aug-19 | 300 |
| 2 | Oct-19 | 800 |
| 2 | Nov-19 | 50 |
| 2 | Dec-19 | 40 |

this is my final table on which I want to map balance from balance table

| ID | Month | Apr-19 | Jul-19 | Aug-19 | Oct-19 | Nov-19 | Dec-19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apr-19 | 100 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Jul-19 |  | 200 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Aug-19 |  |  | 300 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Oct-19 |  |  |  | 800 |  |  |
| 2 | Nov-19 |  |  |  |  | 50 |  |
| 2 | Dec-19 |  |  |  |  |  | 40 |

I tried using case when condition but it seems its very long process, i want this to be done in SAS

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
data have;
input ID Month :anydtdte. Balance;
format Month monyy6.;
datalines;
1 Apr-19 100 
1 Jul-19 200 
1 Aug-19 300 
2 Oct-19 800 
2 Nov-19 50  
2 Dec-19 40  
;

proc sort data = have;
   by ID Month;
run;

proc transpose data = have out = want(drop = _:);
   by ID Month;
   id Month;
   var Balance;
run;
```